# Bash zenity list - issue with reading user's choice

Tags: bash

I have a script written in bash.
In one place I have a zenity list with a few options:

```
menu=("first option" "second option" "third option")
answer=`zenity --list --column=Menu "${menu[@]}" --height 170`
```

After that, when user choose first option I want to do something, when user choose second - something else, etc.

But idk how can I use the variable answer in If statement:

```
if [ option1 ]; then
    ...do something...
elif [ option2 ]; then
    ... do something else...
else
    ... do something different...
fi
```

When I chose first option and uses: echo "$answer", it printed "first option"

But when I tried:

```
if [ $answer = "first option" ]; then
    ....
fi
```

It didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't worked"? Maybe you need to enclose `$answer` in quotes, like this: `"$answer" = "first option"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `$answer` in `""` to avoid [`word splitting`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

menu=("first option" "second option" "third option")
answer=`zenity --list --column=Menu "${menu[@]}" --height 170`

if [ "$answer" = "first option" ]; then
    printf "First option has been chosen\n"
fi
```

Also, it's [recommended](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006) to use `$(...)` instead of backticks. Replace:

```
answer=`zenity --list --column=Menu "${menu[@]}" --height 170`
```

with:

```
answer=$(zenity --list --column=Menu "${menu[@]}" --height 170)
```

**EDIT**:

I was also going to suggest using `case` here but it has already been suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614473/3691891).

Answer (score 0):

Except for the quoting, `if [ "$answer" = "first option" ]` should work. You might want to use a `case` statement here:

```
case "$answer" in 
    "${menu[0]}") 
        echo do stuff for first 
        ;; 
    "${menu[1]}") 
        echo do stuff for second 
        ;; 
    "${menu[2]}") 
        echo do stuff for third 
        ;; 
esac
```